# asp.net mvc and fckeditor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, fckeditor, richtextediting

would like to use fckeditor or similar for building/editing webpages on the fly
but there are a few other old questions where there are issues

am looking for any recent experiences/alternatives ?

thanks

Comment: what issues do you have with fckeditor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a pretty easy time integrating fckeditor in my asp.net mvc app. The fact that mvc and regular webforms co-exist seamlessly made including the free fckupload utility a snap. I highly reccomend it.

Comment: did you setup the image/file browser and image/uploader ?

Answer (score 1):

http://tinymce.moxiecode.com is not bad

Comment: seems a bit slow compared to fckeditor in my unscientific testing - i.e. opening the demo pages for each in different tabs, fck loads faster

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the functionality you need. If it's a simple one like the one used here at StackOverflow, there's a [Markdown Editor](http://wmd-editor.com/).

Comment: Anytime you post a question or an answer on StackOverflow, you are typing into a MarkDown editor. Jeff Atwood has blogged about it many times and even says so in this post on meta.stackoverflow:
http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1777/what-html-tags-are-allowed-on-stack-overflow-server-fault-and-super-user